# CSS работает некорректно

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Баги начались после того, как я поменял цвет текста в body.После этого, почти все стили слетели, за исключением цвета надписей и их размера(они почему то работают).Также в CSS перестал почему-то подсвечиваться header.

До бага все выглядело так: https://wampi.ru/image/RcZDZO6

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #f6950a;


/* Header */
.header {
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 30px;

 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.header_inner {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

.header_logo {
 padding-top: 0px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Nav */
.nav {
 font-size: 19px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.nav_link {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 0 10px;
 position: relative;

 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.nav_link:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 3px;

 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0;

 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;

 transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.nav_link:hover {
 color: white;
}

.nav_link.active {
 color: black;
}

.nav_link:hover:after,
.nav_link.active:after {
 opacity: 1;
}

.nav_link.active {
 opacity: yellow;
}


/* Container */
 .container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }


 /* Intro */
 .intro {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  background: url(../image/back.jpeg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }

 .intro_inner {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 550px;
 }

 .intro_title {
  padding-top: 150px;

  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1;

  color: #a05e2d;

 }

 .intro_title:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;

  width: 499px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 13px 20px 10px 3px;

  background-color: black;
 }


 /* Button */
 .btn {
  margin: 8px 0 0 167px;
  padding: 10px 15px;

  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;

  border: 4px dotted black;

 font-size: 19px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  transition: background 0.2s linear, color 0.2s linear;
 }

 .btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #a05e2d;
 }


 /* Intro-slider */
 .intro_slider {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .slider_inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

 .slider_item {
  padding: 20px 0;

  border-top: 4px solid;
  width: 23%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: relative;

  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;

 }

 .slider_item.active {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 .slider_item.active:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 3px;

  background-color: black;

  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .slider_number {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 700;
 }


 /* Section */
 .section {
  padding: 80px 0 ;
 }

 .section_header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 950px;

  margin: 0 auto 40px;

  text-align: center;
 }

 .section_title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: black;

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Geek Universe</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

 <header class="header">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="header_inner">
    <div class="header_logo">Geek Universe</div>

    <nav class="nav">
     <a class="nav_link active" href="#">About</a>
     <a class="nav_link" href="#">Service</a>
     <a class="nav_link" href="#">Blog</a>
     <a class="nav_link" href="#">Work</a>
     <a class="nav_link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header> 

<div class="intro">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="intro_inner">
   <h2 class="intro_title">A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...</h2>

   <a class="btn" href="#">Learn More</a>
  </div>

  <div class="intro_slider">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="slider_inner">
     <div class="slider_item active">
      <span class="slider_number">01</span>
      intro
     </div>
         <div class="slider_item">
      <span class="slider_number">02</span>
      work
     </div> 
            <div class="slider_item">
      <span class="slider_number">03</span>
      about
     </div>
         <div class="slider_item">
      <span class="slider_number">04</span>
      contacts
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>

<section class="section">
 <div class="container">

  <div class="section_header">
   <h2 class="section_title">What this site is about?</h2>
   <div class="section_text">
    <p>The main topic of this site is interesting information about characters, events, and technologies from such beautiful universes as Star Wars, the Marvel-Universe, the DC-Universe and others.</p>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</section>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Забыли поставить `}` после стилей body

Comment: да вы издеваетесь...Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в body нет закрывающей скобки **}**